# Classifying new observations into two bivariate categories

Tags: distributions, probability, classification

I have two bivariate distributions $A$ and $B$. For some new observation $x$, I would like to calculate the probability that it belongs to $A$ and not $B$.

I can assume that $A$ and $B$ are bivariate normal distributions (but if there is a method that doesn't assume that I'd like to know), but I can't assume their covariance matrices are the same. So far, I've calculated the mahalanobis distance from $x$ to $A$ and from $x$ to $B$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

I should also point out that I'll be doing this for many subjects for whom the distance between $A$ and $B$ will not be the same. If there is some way to take this into account when evaluating $P(x\in A ~\wedge \notin B)$, that'd be nice too.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you know the parameters of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I'm estimating them from data. Does that count?

Comment: Sure, it just requires a somewhat different approach than if you know the parameters a priori.

Comment: Should have asked this up front - do you have observations where you know which group each observation belongs to?  Or is classifying the existing data points going to be part of the problem?

Comment: Now that you've computed squared Mahalanobid distance from point _x_ to the centre of a distribution you go on and compute PDF(_x_) in the bivariate distribution. Classify _x_ to that distribution where the PDF is larger. If prior probability of belonging to A and B distributions aren't equal, use the priors as coefficients (multiply PDFs by them).